# Laravel - How to Create Recursive Select option dropdownlist

Tags: laravel

I am developing a web application with Laravel-5.8. I have this model:

```
class Staff extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
      'staff_code',
      'manager_id',
      'first_name',
      'last_name',
  ];

 public function manager()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Staff','manager_id');
 }

 public function fullName()
 {
  return $this->staff_code . ' - ' . $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
 }
```

While creating staff data, I want to select a Manager for each Staff from the staff table and save it as manager_id into the same table, but display as manager name. Still from the same table.

**Controller**

```
public function create()
{
  $managers       =       Staff::all();
  return view('staff.create')
    ->with('managers', $managers);
}
```

view

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label"> Manager:</label>
  <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Manager" tabindex="1" name="manager_id" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="">Select Line Manager</option>
     @if($managers->count() > 0 )
        @foreach($managers as $manager)
          <option value="{{$manager->id}}">{{$manager->fullName}}</option>
        @endforeach
     @endif
  </select>
</div>
```

I observed that nothing is loaded in the dropdownlist. How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that `$managers` is empty!  Does your database actually have data?  Do you see data when you do `dd($managers);` after you retrieve Staff:all()?

Comment: Also, you don't need the outer `@if()` block.  `@foreach()` will only render if the collection has at least one item.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$manager->fullName`, you're using Eloquent relationship which is not exists in this case. You should use this instead:

```
$manager->fullName()
```

Besides this, I suggest you use the [Laravel accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this specific case.
As a result, you will have such a code in model:

```
 public function getFullNameAttribute()
 {
     return $this->staff_code . ' - ' . $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
 }
```

So we can rewrite the code in the view as follows:

```
@foreach($managers as $manager)
    <option value="{{$manager->id}}">{{$manager->full_name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I followed your code, but the dropdown list is still empty and there is data in the staff table.

Comment: @mikefolu Could you provide the result of this code ? 
 `dd(Staff::with('manager')->get()->toArray());`